# syntax error unexpected with

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1064

```
with ntable (date,pnodeid,rtavg)
   as
    ( 
      select date,pnodeid, (select avg(myaverage) from (values (hour8),(hour9),(hour10),(hour11),(hour12),(hour13),(hour14),(hour15),(hour16),(hour17),(hour18),(hour19),(hour20),(hour21),(hour22),(hour23)) as TblAverage(myaverage)) from pjm_realtime 
     )
 select date,rtavg  
from ntable
where rtavg > 65 and pnodeid = '51288' and weekday(date) between 0 and 4 and year(date) >= '2014';
```

I am getting 1064 error. Trying to get the average of multiple columns and use it as a search criteria

Comment: MySQL doesn't have CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have CTE/WITH; however, you can simply subquery like so:

```
select date, rtavg  
from
( 
  select date, pnodeid, (select avg(myaverage) from (values (hour8),(hour9),(hour10),(hour11),(hour12),(hour13),(hour14),(hour15),(hour16),(hour17),(hour18),(hour19),(hour20),(hour21),(hour22),(hour23)) as TblAverage(myaverage)) rtavg from pjm_realtime 
) btable
where rtavg > 65 and pnodeid = '51288' and weekday(date) between 0 and 4 and year(date) >= '2014';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` syntax is a feature of SQL-99 that MySQL does not support.

I wrote about this lack of feature here: [WITHer Recursive Queries?](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/02/11/wither-recursive-queries/)

In April 2016, I went to a presentation by a panel of MySQL development staff, and they said they intend to support `WITH` syntax in the next major version, MySQL 8. But that probably won't be ready for a couple of years.